# ¿Cómo poder leer por teclado int o String según lo que se introduzca, en Java?

Tags: java

Estoy creando un programa en el que si introducen del 1 al 4 se ejecutan unas opciones, pero si escriben salir, debería saltar el mensaje *Ha seleccionado salir del programa*, y con los enteros ok, pero el salir no sé cómo conseguirlo. Adjunto código con lo que estoy probando.

```
int opcion = 0;
    String opcion2=null;
    boolean salir=false;
    
    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    try {
    
    while(!salir) {
    
    System.out.println("Bienvenido a clase PC:");
    System.out.println("Opcion 1. Crear nuevo objeto");
    System.out.println("Opcion 2. Modificar objeto");
    System.out.println("Opcion 3. Eliminar objeto");
    System.out.println("Opcion 4. Salir (pulse 4, 0 o escriba salir)");
    System.out.println("Opción 5. Ver listado actual de PCs");
    
    System.out.print("Introduzca una de las opciones: ");
    opcion=teclado.nextInt();
    opcion2=teclado.nextLine();
    teclado.nextLine();//Limpiamos el buffer de lectura (otra manera sería leer los enteros como int ram=Integer.parseInt(teclado.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 3):

No hagas la lectura teclado.nextInt(). Lee con teclado.nextLine() y verificas si es "salir". Si no lo es, entonces, la misma línea (opcion2), intenta convertirla a entero con Integer.parseInt(opcion2)

Si no ha metido un entero, sino cualquier otra cosa, te saltará una excpción, así que deberías poner el teclado.nextLine() y la verificación de si es "salir" o un entero en un bucle,  hasta que la opción sea correcta.

Algo como esto

```
while(true) {
   opcion2 = teclado.readLine();
   if ("salir".equals(opcion2)) {
      System.exit(0);
   }
   try {
      opcion = Integer.parseInt(opcion2);
      break;
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.println("Debes introducir un numero o la palabra salir");
   }
}
```

Se bueno.

Answer (score 1):

La forma mas sencilla es hacer que el `Scanner` coja el input como tipo `String`, para ello usa el método `Scanner.nextLine()` y luego realice las operaciones de conversión a `int`.

Aqui tienes un ejemplo de un metodo que te podria servir.

```java
  private int option() {
    final String option = SCANNER.nextLine();
    if (option.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
      return 0;
    }
    try {
      return Integer.parseInt(option);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      // En caso de que te introducan algun texto que no sea "exit" te 
      // devolvera un valor por defecto el cual tu puedes controlar en tu 
      // codigo
      return Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

La clase [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) tiene varias funciones útiles: [`hasNextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--), [`hasNext`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext--), [`nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) y [`next`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--), entre otras. Te recomiendo que leas la documentación.

`hasNext` verifica que haya algo para leer y `hasNextInt` que sea específicamente un entero.

`next` lee la primera palabra que encuentre y `nextInt` el primer entero.

Puedes hacer algo así:

```
var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while (scanner.hasNext()){
    mostrarMenu();

    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        int opcion = scanner.nextInt();
        elegirOpcion(opcion);
    }
    else {
        String entrada = scanner.next();
        if (entrada.equals("salir"))
            break;
    }
}
```

De acuerdo al alcance que necesites, puedes definir la variable del scanner como local o miembro estático.

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##hVLLUoMwFN3zFXeyabAjM75WHT/ARXXBUl3cwpWmDQGT0Oo4fJWf4IdhQqEWS/VsIJfz4B5Y4QbPV@m6aUReFtrCyg0iiSqLzmbB4ayyQvpZUFYLKRJIJBoDcxQKPoIAHLoHxqJ1l00hUsgLYzXqOamKhz3PI343lvKoqGxUaqGsVJx5FgtnLac@aUmSMqEfykQUijslFO2td//DvCP9Z567dXhsnSh7fAbUmTn03aAGk6BSpOEWFG0h3p14lyh8wp6@XQpJwDtFtERzT2@Wh@GPo8egowO5h3g50t8pbwFDj5a778K9XC9SvWJ2xB8UOeinRx0M@YZGYndtASm3RIq/osdyxz59TEAm0WIhvj7hiTGY7g2nMGGTERtfTceJ6LVCaTgzKIVmYXhE9lhowvWpBevux6ib5gJSuIQruIbWDm6@AQ).

Answer (score -1):

Ni si quiera es necesario convertir las respuesta a int.
Crea solo una variable "opcion" de tipo String y luego utiliza el métodos opcion.equals("") y entre las comillas puedes poner tanto la palabra "salir" como cualquiera de los números.